# Insert into mongodb with perl

Tags: perl, mongodb, insert

I wrote a script to insert items into [mongodb](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use MongoDB;
use Data::Dumper;

my $hostname = "localhost";
my $port = 27017;

my $conn = MongoDB::Connection->new( "host" => "$hostname", 
                                     "port" => $port );
my $db = $conn->test;
my $user_stats = $db->test_stats;

# Insert line
$user_stats->insert({'user_id' => 123, 
                     'pointA'=> 12, 
                     'pointB' => 13, 
                     'total' => 25, } );

my $myStr = $user_stats->find_one();
print Dumper($myStr);
```

The code work well.
However when I change to `insert line` to

```
my $a = "{'user_id' => 123, 
          'pointA' => 12,
          'pointB' => 13,
          'total' => 25}";

$user_stats->insert($a);
```

It doesn't work given back error:`not a reference at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/sun4-solaris/MongoDB/Collection.pm line 296.`

Comment: Well, don't change working code to non-working code.  Why do you want to make `$a` a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`insert` method on `MongoDB::Collection`](http://search.cpan.org/~kristina/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/Collection.pm#insert_%28%24object,_%24options?%29) expects a hash-ref:

> **insert ($object, $options?)**
>
> Inserts the given `$object` into the database and returns it's id value. `$object` can be a hash reference, a reference to an array with an even number of elements, or a `Tie::IxHash`.

So, the usual approach is to use a hash-ref and your `$a` is a string, not a hash-ref. The other options are an array-ref that can be easily "cast" to a hash-ref (i.e. it has the form `[key, value, key, value, ...]`) or a [`Tie::IxHash`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tie-IxHash/) (which is a hash that maintains order); your `$a` string isn't one of those either.